# How can Vulkan vkCmdDrawIndexedIndirect with different texture for each inner draw command

Tags: vulkan

For example, I have 10k meshes to render, each of which will be attached with a different texture. Again, the textures are of different resolutions, hence cannot be arranged in a texture array. Each frame, a subset of the 10k meshes will be selected and rendered.

Constructing a indriect draw command buffer by a previous transform feedback render pass, I can render the meshes in another single draw call. The question is how can I assign the relevant texture between the draw commands.

In OpenGL, by offering texture handle in uivec2 format, different textures can be accessed via the bindless texture feature.

However, in Vulkan, the bindless feature is not included. Should I just abandon the indirect draw routine, and recorde a large command buffer every frame, and update the descriptor's back image in a loop? Or, should I create a array descriptor, assign different image into the elements, and update texture ID through push constant in a loop? Or, there are some better solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: "*Again, the textures are of different resolutions, hence cannot be arranged in a texture array.*" You can always *make* the textures have equal resolution.

Comment: Won't texture atlas help here? Place image in a single, huge texture image or in multiple arrays of a single layered image. Then You just need to provide appropriate texture coordinates to vertices.

Answer (score 5):

If you are set on not rescaling your textures so that they fit into an array texture, then you can create an array of samplers. That's generally how this is handled.

In Vulkan, arrayed descriptors are considered a single descriptor of the array's base type. So you can attach all of the textures in question to this single descriptor, assigning each model a location in the array.

The `DrawIndex` input (requiring the `shaderDrawParamters` feature/extension) to the vertex shader tells you which drawing command in the indirect call created that vertex. So you can use this to fetch per-model data, which would include the texture's index for that model. Plus, the index is dynamically uniform, which is good, since you need that.

Of course, in order to do this at all, your Vulkan implementation must support `shaderSampledImageArrayDynamicIndexing`. Most desktop implementations do, but few non-desktop ones do.

Comment: There's a good blog post on using arrays of textures here:  http://kylehalladay.com/blog/tutorial/vulkan/2018/01/28/Textue-Arrays-Vulkan.html

Comment: Additionally, you can store different resolution textures efficiently in a sparse texture array, but only if you're willing to jump through the extra hoops on the shader side to deal with fetching sizes and dealing with boundary conditions yourself instead of letting the texture hardware do it.

Comment: I think this is a decent solution. Thanks for sharing your wit. But one more question, please. Assuming that the mesh number can only be determined in runtime, how to set the length of the sampler array in shader? Should I set a large number like 2147483647 to ensure sufficiency, or is there a dynamic arbitrary-length sampler array mechanism in Vulkan shader?